# How to replace ascii codes with characters in custom settings or buffer?

Tags: org-mode, init-file, customize, org-tags, ascii

I customized `org-tag-alist` using the built-in customization interface. This stored the values in `("tag") . <ascii key value>)` pairs like this:

```
  ("ez" . 90)
  ("pin" . 73)
  ("per" . 61)
  ("inprog" . 78)
  ("maybe" . 66)
```

Is there any way to view this data with the ascii codes converted to characters, like this?

```
  ("ez" . ?Z)
  ("pin" . ?I)
  ("per" . ?=)
  ("inprog" . ?N)
  ("maybe" . ?B)
```

Comment: Not sure whether it makes a difference in this case, but you might want a character and *not* a string: `("ez" . ?Z)  ...`

Comment: What @NickD said. If you really want strings, please edit your question, including its title, to reflect that it's not about chars but about strings.

Comment: Do you actually use single-character abbreviations for 200 tags?

Comment: @NickD Yes, I want characters. I've corrected the the question. No, I don't have keys assigned for all 200 tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a replace regexp :

```
M-x query-replace-regexp \([[:digit:]]\{2\}\) → \,(format "?%c" (string-to-number \1))
```

instead of `(string-to-number \1)`you could prefer `\#1` .

Comment: See my comment on the question: you might need to change the format.

Comment: That character regexp is exactly what I was looking for. Using 'format' with 'string-to-number' was the missing piece of the puzzle for me.